# Rhino Mocks SetupResult fails

Tags: c#, mocking

```
public class simplemocking
{
    public interface IFoo
    {
        int foo ();
    }
    public void fii()
    {
        IFoo foo = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IFoo> ();
        SetupResult.For (foo.foo ()).Return (5).Repeat.Any ();
        Console.WriteLine (foo.foo ());
    }
}
```

Exception:

> Invalid call, the last call has been
>   used or no call has been made (make
>   sure that you are calling a virtual
>   (C#) / Overridable (VB) method).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try to use extension methods instead of SetupFor

Replace the second line by :

```
foo.Stub(f => f.foo()).Return(5).Repeat.Any();
```